# Separate Cognitive Search query from ChatGPT interaction without losing citations

Tags: openai-api, chatgpt-api, azure-openai, chat-gpt-4

Azure's OpenAI service allows you to pass in an `AzureChatExtensionConfiguration` and have it  run a cognitive search query against your data, passing the results to ChatGPT for 'context'.

Is it possible to separate these two steps? I want to run the cognitive search part, get x number of results, then pass that to ChatGPT and have it use that context. *However*, I want the chat results to have the same citations / references that the first approach does.

i.e. With the first approach, I can use the result JSON to get the citations like so: `Choices[0].Message.AzureExtensionsContext.Messages[0].Content`

This gives me a list of Citation objects:

```
private class Citation
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string FilePath { get; set; }
    public string Url { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
}
```

Additionally, within the message content itself (i.e. `Choices[0].Message.Content`), there will be citation links in the format `[doc1]`, `[doc2]`, etc...

I don't want to lose this functionality, but I do want to insert a bit more logic into the gap between the cognitive search and the ChatGPT call - e.g., checking the list of results and if they're no sufficient, taking some other action.

Is this possible, or is the structure of response from the `GetChatCompletionsAsync` with the `AzureChatExtensionsOptions` some proprietary internal feature to the Azure OpenAI?